# More detailed monitoring of Pod states

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Our Pods usually spend at least a minute and up to several minutes in the `Pending` state, the events via `kubectl describe pod x` yield:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age        From               Message
  ----    ------     ----       ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  <unknown>  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned testing/runner-2zyekyp-project-47-concurrent-0tqwl4 to host
  Normal  Pulled     55s        kubelet, host  Container image "registry.com/image:c1d98da0c17f9b1d4ca81713c138ee2e" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    55s        kubelet, host  Created container build
  Normal  Started    54s        kubelet, host  Started container build
  Normal  Pulled     54s        kubelet, host  Container image "gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-6214287e" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    54s        kubelet, host  Created container helper
  Normal  Started    54s        kubelet, host  Started container helper
```

The provided information is not exactly detailed as to figure out exactly what is happening.

**Question:**

How can we gather more detailed metrics of what exactly and when exactly something happens in regards to get a Pod running in order to troubleshoot which step exactly needs how much time?

Special interest would be the metric of how long it takes to mount a volume.

Answer (score 1):

Check kubelet and kube scheduler logs because kube scheduler schedules the pod to a node and kubelet starts the pod on that node and reports the status as ready.

```
journalctl -u kubelet # after logging into the kubernetes node

kubectl logs kube-scheduler -n kube-system
```

Describe the pod, deployment, replicaset to get more details

```
kubectl describe pod podnanme -n namespacename
kubectl describe deploy deploymentnanme -n namespacename
kubectl describe rs replicasetnanme -n namespacename
```

Check events

```
kubectl get events -n namespacename
```

Describe the nodes and check available resources and status which should be ready.

```
kubectl describe node nodename
```